How to find out if we can add a user to our Telegram group or not?
I wrote a source that adds a large number of users from one group to another group in Telegram. But I have a problem, many people have closed the ability to add to their group. I want to add a section to my bot that checks this limit before adding it so that it goes faster.
import asyncio
import random
from pyrogram.errors import FloodWait, UsernameNotOccupied, UserNotMutualContact, PeerFlood, ChatAdminRequired

addcount = 0

async def add(client, user_id, chat_id):
    global addcount
    try:
        result = await client.add_chat_members(chat_id, user_id)
        print(result)
        if result:
            addcount += 1
            print(f"Added member = {addcount}")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(8, 12))
    except FloodWait as e:
        print(f"FloodWait: Sleeping for {e.seconds} seconds")
        await asyncio.sleep(e.seconds)
    except UsernameNotOccupied:
        print("Username not found!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))
    except UserNotMutualContact:
        print("User not a mutual contact!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))
    except PeerFlood:
        print("PeerFlood: Account limited!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))
    except ChatAdminRequired:
        print("ChatAdminRequired: Admin privileges required!")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error: {e}")
        await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(6, 10))

My work will go much faster

This approach can be used to check if the user can be added to the target group.
async def check_user_status(client, user_id, target_chat_id):
    try:
        chat_member = await client.get_chat_member(target_chat_id, user_id)
        return False  # User is already in the group
    except UserPrivacyRestricted:
        return False  # User has privacy settings restricting adding to groups
    except UserNotParticipant:
        return True  # User can be added
    except UserNotMutualContact:
        return False  # User is not a mutual contact
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unexpected error occurred: {e}")
        return False

Example Usage:
can_add = await check_user_status(client, user_id, target_chat_id)
if can_add:
    try:
        await client.add_chat_members(target_chat_id, user_id)
        print(f"Added user {user_id} to the group.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to add user {user_id}: {e}")
else:
    print(f"Cannot add user {user_id} to the group.")

For making it more fast, you can try using Multithreading. But telegram may rate-limit you for this.

I used this method, but when the function returns "True" the user is not added to the group

I thought you will do that yourself. I edited now with an example.

I had done this work. My problem was that even though users were limited to add, the "check_user_status" function still returns the True value and adding is not done further.
